How can I get the router data in nested routes in Angular
This is my routers define.
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sys',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/sys/sys.routers').then(m => m.SYS_ROUTES),
        canActivate: [unAuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  },
];

This is the SYS_ROUTRES on /pages/sys/sys.routers.
export const SYS_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'menu', component: MenuManageComponent, data: {title: '菜单管理'} },
];

I want get the router data in LayoutComponent. Here is my code.
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {   

    // Direct access, not trigger router events.
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); // undefined
    })
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data); // undefined
    this.router.routerState.root.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); // undefined
    })

    console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.data); // undefined
  }
}


When I route to sys/menu. The above get ways is always undefined.
Neither Router nor ActivatedRoute can correctly obtain the router data.
How can I get the router data?

You can use the firstChild property of activatedRoute to access the data property from the parent.
But note: The first child must be present for this code to work, so I am adding typescript safe navigation (?.) to prevent errors.
So the code will be
this.activatedRoute?.firstChild?.data?.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); // undefined
})
// or
console.log(this.activatedRoute?.firstChild?.snapshot?.data);

